# Jquery Mobile textarea shrink after entering many characters

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I am currently having problem with project. When text is entered on the textarea, it automatically autogrow as more and more text is entered but after awhile, it shrinks that no text can be seen. The text are not deleted nor lost. How can I fix this?

```
<p><textarea name="instruction" id="instruction" placeholder="Enter Intruction here"></textarea></p>
```

[image: Before Entering Text]

[image: After Entering Text]

Answer (score 1):

you need to add rows and cols (amount of characters)

as well as font size in styleing

```
<textarea name="instruction" id="instruction" placeholder="Enter Intruction here" cols="42" rows="1" ></textarea>
```

and CSS such as:

```
textarea {
font-size: 1em;
}
```

---

Edit:

then perhaps try

```
box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
```

Comment: JQM ignores `cols` and `rows`

Comment: i added another possible fix. please try the font sizing as well, it changes size of box.